# get_include_path() dont understand

Tags: path, get, include

/*adding all directories to the include path e.g.classes,pages,modules,inc,template directory where DS means directory seperator */

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR),array(
realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.CLASSES_DIR),
realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.PAGES_DIR),
realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.MOD_DIR),
realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.INC_DIR),
realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.TEMPLATE_DIR),
get_include_path()
)));
```

if i include all directory path what is get_include_path doing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This construct is used to add some more paths to the include path:

```
set_include_path(
```

The `implode` chains the following include paths:

```
  implode(PATH_SEPARATOR,array(
```

These are the new paths:

```
    realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.CLASSES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.PAGES_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.MOD_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.INC_DIR),
    realpath(ROOT_DIR.DS.TEMPLATE_DIR),
```

Here, the old paths, which have already been set, are appended to the end of the new include path:

```
    get_include_path()
  )
);
```

Comment: thank u so much. On this project set_include_path() just used once here in config.php  file. so i dont understand why get_include_path() used here as we are setting new paths here for the first time , no older path should be available

Comment: Otoh it doesn't hurt to include it if other paths are set